# Как добавить заголовок с именем в приходящем заказе в магазине woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть магазин на `woocommerce`.

Меня всегда интересовало, почему в заказе нет заголовка перед именем.

Как можно его добавить и желательно без костылей, которые слетают при каждом обновлении плагина магазина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил таким способом, возможно он немного корявый, но работает. 
Стили для админки нужны потому что по какой-то причине при таком решении имя и фамилия выводится дважды: как было изначально и уже с лейблами. 
Если будут решения лучше - с удовольствием их отмечу.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'custom_admin_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
function custom_admin_billing_fields( $billing_fields ) {
    $billing_fields['first_name']['show'] = true;
    $billing_fields['last_name']['show'] = true;
    return $billing_fields;
}

add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
#order_data .order_data_column_container .address>p:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
  </style>';
}
```

Comment: выводятся дважды скорей всего потому что вначале выводится `$order->get_formatted_billing_address()` , он идет до фильтра woocommerce_admin_billing_fields, для него есть отдельный фильтр `woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address` посмотрите код в файле `class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php` 322 строка.

Comment: если я добавляю такой фильтр, то пишет, что платежный адрес не найден `add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 );
function filter_function_name( $billing_fields, $that ){
 $billing_fields['first_name'] = "";
 $billing_fields['last_name'] = "";
 return $billing_fields;
}` а в массиве $billing_fields только прямые ключи без атрибута `show`

Answer (score 1):

Эта форма выводится в классе `WC_Meta_Box_Order_Data` в нем есть фильтр с лейблами `woocommerce_admin_billing_fields` , если в лейбле стоит `'show'  => false` он не выводится.Так же есть фильтр `woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address` - это для самого первого поля в этой колонке, он вызывается через метод заказа `get_formatted_billing_address()` поэтому я не уверен что применится только в этой форме.

Comment: предлагаете как-то так? 
`add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'custom_admin_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
function custom_admin_billing_fields( $billing_fields ) {
    $billing_fields = array(
        'first_name' => array(
            'label' => __( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ),
            'show'  => true
        ),
        'last_name'  => array(
            'label' => __( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ),
            'show'  => true
        )
    );
    return $billing_fields;
}`